# How to make `latexmk` run the appropriate amount of times

Tags: compiling, emacs, auctex, latexmk

System:

Ubuntu 13.04, Texlive2012, Emacs 24.something, I run Emacs from the terminal and not the GUI, and I have server mode on in Emacs.

When compiling my latex documents, I use `AucTeX` in `emacs` to run `latexmk` but `latexmk` only runs once and will say you should run `latexmk` again and then reason whether it be references or something else.  Isn't the point of `latexmk` to run the appropriate amount of times from the get go?

How can I have `latexmk` do this with out me telling `emacs` to run it again?

My latex portion of my `.emacs` is below in case there is something I need to add or remove from it to get the desired results.

```lisp
;;============AucTex===========                                                 
(require 'tex-site)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'turn-on-reftex)
(setq reftex-plug-into-AUCTex t)
(global-font-lock-mode t)
(setq font-lock-maximum-decoration t)

;;============ Latexmk setup==============                                        
(defun run-latexmk ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((TeX-save-query nil)
        (TeX-process-asynchronous nil)
        (master-file (TeX-master-file)))
    (TeX-save-document "")
    (TeX-run-TeX "latexmk"
                (TeX-command-expand "latexmk -pdflatex='pdflatex -file-line-error  \
                                  -synctex=1' -pdf %s" 'TeX-master-file)
                 master-file))
    (if (plist-get TeX-error-report-switches (intern master-file))
        (TeX-next-error t)
      (progn
        (demolish-tex-help)
        (minibuffer-message "latexmk: done."))))

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (lambda ()
    (push
     '("Latexmk" "latexmk -pdf %s" TeX-run-TeX nil t
       :help "Run Latexmk on file")
     TeX-command-list)))

;; Set okular to open with C-c C-v view option                                      
(defun Okular-make-url () (concat
     "file://"
     (expand-file-name (funcall file (TeX-output-extension) t)
                       (file-name-directory (TeX-master-file))
                       "#src:"
                       (TeX-current-line)
                       (expand-file-name (TeX-master-directory))
                       "./"
                       (TeX-current-file-name-master-relative))))

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook '(lambda ()
        (add-to-list 'TeX-expand-list
                     '("%u" Okular-make-url))))
(setq TeX-view-program-list
      '(("Okular" "okular --unique %u")))
(setq TeX-view-program-selection '((output-pdf "Okular")))

(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.                                       
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.                    
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.                           
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.                               
 '(TeX-PDF-mode t)
 '(TeX-newline-function (quote newline-and-indent))
 '(TeX-source-correlate-method (quote synctex))
 '(TeX-source-correlate-mode t)
 '(TeX-source-correlate-start-server t)
 '(TeX-view-program-list (quote (("Okular" "okular -unique %o#src:%n%b"))) t)
 '(TeX-view-program-selection (quote ((output-pdf "Okular"))) t)
 '(compilation-auto-jump-to-first-error t))
```

Below is my `.latexmkrc` file

```
$pdf_mode = 1;
$pdflatex = 'pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -synctex=1';
```

**Edit**

Per John Collins' request, here is the message I received when running `latexmk`

```
You should run LaTeX again to get references right, {9} pages
```

Even though it says LaTeX, `latexmk` was ran here is the output to show this:

```
Running `Latexmk' on `TidalForce' with ``latexmk -pdf TidalForce''
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 11 Nov. 2012, version: 4.35.
**** Report bugs etc to John Collins <collins at phys.psu.edu>. ****
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
Rule 'pdflatex': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'TidalForce.tex'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
```

---

As John Collins mentioned, here is the better format for the `.emacs` and `.latexmkrc` file.

> ```
> ;; ============ Latexmk setup ==============                                        
> (defun run-latexmk ()
>   (interactive)
>   (let ((TeX-save-query nil)
>         (TeX-process-asynchronous nil)
>         (master-file (TeX-master-file)))
>     (TeX-save-document "")
>     (TeX-run-TeX "latexmk"
>                  (TeX-command-expand "latexmk -pdf %s" 'TeX-master-file)
>                  master-file))
>     (if (plist-get TeX-error-report-switches (intern master-file))
>         (TeX-next-error t)
>       (progn
>         (demolish-tex-help)
>         (minibuffer-message "latexmk: done."))))
>
> (add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (lambda ()
>     (push
>      '("Latexmk" "latexmk -pdf %s" TeX-run-TeX nil t
>        :help "Run Latexmk on file")
>      TeX-command-list)))
> ```

---

`.latexmkrc` setup:

> ```
> $pdflatex = 'pdflatex --shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -synctex=1 %O %S';
> ```

Comment: Does `latexmk` run `pdflatex` only once? If you run it another time, do you get an error `All files are up to date`? If yes, the problem is only related to `auctex`'s log parser, not to `latexmk`.

Comment: @T.Verron yes it runs only once and no when I run it again it will update all the references or whatever it was suggesting the reason to run again.

Comment: @dustin I thought latexmk was a Perl script which is so clever that knows how many times to run various commands? If the above is indeed the case it almost defeats the purpose of using it. I use home coked Makefiles on one hand. Going back to your original question there must be some way to do it by editing .emacs if I recall correctly but I am a vi user (no flaming) and I forgot how to fix that in Lisp. This is trivial to do in vi so in Emacs should be even easier as it is fully programmable editor.

Comment: @PredragPunosevac I don't have a problem with `Vim` I used to use it until a plugin corrupted everything and removing it didn't fix the problem.  Yes it is a perl script and it is supposed to be clever but in my case it has been having learning challenges.

Comment: @dustin I use nvi. I do not use Vim. I have the following line in my .exrc map ^X :w^M:!make pdf clean-ps %^M and write a Makefile per working directory.

Comment: @dustin Could you show exactly what messages you get.  You are completely correct that latexmk should run pdflatex (etc) as many times as needed to resolve cross references.  So you should not be seeing a message from latexmk saying you need to run it again. But you say you are seeing such a message. That's very strange, and we'll need to see exactly what output you are seeing to make a diagnosis.

Comment: @dustin Try small test to narrow down error: Place both [bib.tex](http://www.andy-roberts.net/res/writing/latex/bib.tex) and [sample.bib](http://www.andy-roberts.net/res/writing/latex/sample.bib) in same folder and run `latexmk -pdf bib` from folder at terminal and `bib.pdf` should have right references without any extra latexmk run manually.

Comment: @texenthusiast same thing.  I should run it again to get the reference right

Comment: @dustin with sample.bib and bib.tex  `latexmk` 11 Nov. 2012. Version 4.35 it works for me from terminal.
Tip: Adding a space by pressing bar on the current `.tex` will make a new timestamp of `.tex` file in this way `latexmk` detects for any file changes and run automatically correct number of times.

Comment: I've just seen a problem in the invocation of `latexmk`.  In your definitions of the command lines for `latexmk`, change "%s" to "%O %S".  (Both the "O" and "S" are upper case.)  Try that and see what happens. The "%S" is the correct placeholder for the name of the source file, and the "%O" is for options that `latexmk` may place on the command line.  With the lower case "s" that you have, `latexmk` will function incorrectly.  Also the output from `latexmk` is severely truncated; there should be a minimum of 3 extra lines.  Perhaps `auctex` is eating them.

Comment: @JohnCollins That worked!  Can you make this an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your definitions of the command lines for `latexmk`, change `%s` to `%O %S`. (Both the `O` and `S` are upper case.)  The `%S` is the correct placeholder for the name of the source file, and the `%O` is for options that `latexmk` may place on the command line. With the lower case `s` that you have, `latexmk` doesn't do the substitution for the name of the source file, and the command line passed to `pdflatex` is not the intended one.

### Note added

It turned out later that the above answer was misleading/misinpretable.  There is a configuration of `emacs` to call `latexmk` correctly, and a configuration of `latexmk` to call `pdflatex` as is desired by the OP.  Although `latexmk` can be configured through its command line, which was done in the `emacs` configuration file `.emacs` in the question, it is normally easier and safer to configure `latexmk` in one of its own configuration files.  See [TikZ: compiling a standalone picture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125466/tikz-compiling-a-standalone-picture) for a better configuration.