# TikZ: compiling a standalone picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, compiling, emacs, latexmk, standalone

I am not sure if this is recreate-able through a MWE.  Whenever I compile a standalone `TikZ` picture,  it compiles all my standalone figures in the same folder.  I am using Ubuntu 13.04 and Emacs with server mode running.

[image]

Some of this information may be irrelevant, but I am not sure what is needed to troubleshoot such an issue.  From the screen shot, I have the main document on the left and my `TikZ` picture I am creating on the right.  As you can see, I compiled the figure and `Latexmk` compiled every other standalone `.tex` file too.

```
Output written on sunplanetspacecraft.pdf (1 page, 1117 bytes).
SyncTeX written on sunplanetspacecraft.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on sunplanetspacecraft.log.
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'sunplanetspacecraft.pdf'
Latexmk: All targets (sunplanetspacecraft.pdf) are up-to-date
Latexmk: All targets (transferchoices.pdf) are up-to-date
Latexmk: All targets (transfergeoa.pdf) are up-to-date
Latexmk: All targets (transfergeob.pdf) are up-to-date
Latexmk: All targets (trigidentities.pdf) are up-to-date
Latexmk: All targets (twobodies3D.pdf) are up-to-date
Latexmk: All targets (unitvec.pdf) are up-to-date
Latexmk: All targets (velcomp.pdf) are up-to-date

Latexmk finished at Thu Jul 25 14:12:06
```

I am compiling `sunplanetspacecraft.tex` and none of the files are related to the to this `.tex` file but yet they still were compiled.

I looked through the log file, but I didn't see anything that related to the other files `Latexmk` compiled.  Below is my preamble in case that helps.

```
\documentclass[convert = false]{standalone}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ppl}                                  
\linespread{1.05}          
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}                                  
\usepackage{courier}                                                    
\usepackage{eulervm}                       
\normalfont
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames, svgnames, table]{xcolor}                                             
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
```

The reason I want to resolve this is because one of the another `standalone TikZ` pictures takes about 2minutes to compile which slows down compiling a simple picture.

---

This problem cropped up with another document.  This time my document that calls all my `standalone`s in it tried calling an unrelated `standalone` just because it was in the same folder.

So a MWE (concept) would be to have a a folder, in the folder at a `main.tex`, in the `main.tex`, you need have `\usepackage{standalone}`, then we have two cases:

1. create two `standalone`s to be called in the `main.tex` and compile
   the first one.  When you compile the second one, it will also
   compile the first one.  This wont cause the problem I am having
   since you are probably creating simple documents (not an issue
   though).  Just check the output to see if it compile the other one
   too.  This will be the first issue at the top I mention. Create a
   folder called test.

   main.tex

   ```
       \documentclass{article}
       \usepackage{standalone}
       \usepackage{tikz}
       \begin{document}
       test
       \includestandalone{test1}
       \includestandalone{test2}
       \end{document}
   ```

   test1.tex

   ```
       \documentclass[tikz, convert = false]{standalone}
       \begin{document}
       \begin{tikzpicture}
         \draw (0, 0) -- (2, 0);
       \end{tikzpicture}
       \end{document}
   ```

   test2.tex

   ```
       \documentclass[tikz, convert = false]{standalone}
       \begin{document}
       \begin{tikzpicture}
         \draw (0, 0) -- (-2, 0);
       \end{tikzpicture}
       \end{document}
   ```

   So if I compile `test2.tex`, `test1.tex` compiles also.  This hardly
   causes a slow down but you get the idea.
2. create a standalone not called in the `main.tex`, but this time don't add anything in the file.  Just name it and save it no preamble.  Even though this file isn't being called by the `main.tex`, compiling the `main.tex` file will try and compile this file that doesn't even have a preamble.  It calls because it has a `.tex` extension.  In the same folder, create `test3.tex` which is blank no pre-amble or code and save it.  Now add a line to `main.tex` and compile.  This should cause the error no `\begin{document}` in the main file.  The document will compile fine though but will constantly have that error.  `main.tex` is forcing the compiling of a blank `.tex` file even though it isn't included.

> ```
> ;; ============ Latexmk setup ==============                                        
> (defun run-latexmk ()
>   (interactive)
>   (let ((TeX-save-query nil)
>         (TeX-process-asynchronous nil)
>         (master-file (TeX-master-file)))
>     (TeX-save-document "")
>     (TeX-run-TeX "latexmk"
>                  (TeX-command-expand "latexmk -pdf %O %S" 'TeX-master-file)
>                  master-file))
>     (if (plist-get TeX-error-report-switches (intern master-file))
>         (TeX-next-error t)
>       (progn
>         (demolish-tex-help)
>         (minibuffer-message "latexmk: done."))))
>
> (add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (lambda ()
>     (push
>      '("Latexmk" "latexmk -pdf %S" TeX-run-TeX nil t
>        :help "Run Latexmk on file")
>      TeX-command-list)))
> ```

---

`.latexmkrc` setup:

> $pdflatex = 'pdflatex --shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode %O %S -file-line-error -synctex=1';

Comment: How are you running `Latexmk`?  By default it runs on every `.tex` file (according to http://users.phys.psu.edu/~collins/software/latexmk-jcc/latexmk-437.txt)

Comment: It will be a lot easier for us to help you if you make a real MWE -- put a zip file up somewhere that has an entire directory tree that shows the problem.  Then tell us exactly what commands to run, and what behavior you're seeing, and what behavior you expect.

Comment: You also still need to tell us exactly what command line was used to invoke `latexmk`.  The behavior you are seeing is exactly what happens when the command line is "latexmk", without any file name, whereas the command line should have been "latexmk sunplanetspacecraft.tex".  This was what @JimParis was getting at in his first comment.  Since you are using `emacs` to invoke `latexmk`, it is possible that `emacs` is misconfigured.  The value of `$pdflatex` that you quoted is irrelevant for this issue.

Comment: How have you customized `emacs`/`auctex` to have a `latexmk` command?  The answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199678/how-to-call-latexmk-in-emacs-and-jump-to-next-error suggest how to do this.  Did you possibly omit "%s" in the definition of how to run `latexmk`?  That would be consistent with the symptoms you observe (and I can reproduce them).

Comment: I've looked back at the question @dustin asked before: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115247/how-to-make-latexmk-run-the-appropriate-amount-of-times  There was confusion there, some of it on my part.  There are two parts to the customization.  First is for specifying to `latexmk` how it calls `pdflatex`; this uses `%O %S` (as I recommended) to specify where options and source name are.  But there must also be `%s` in the command line that is defined in `.emacs` to say how `emacs`/`auctex` calls `latexmk`.  You'll need to show us exactly what is in `.emacs` and `latexmkrc`.

Comment: Try the following: First, in `.emacs` only, change the `%O %S` and `%S` to `%s` (lower case).  Second, in `latexmkrc` only, move the `%O %S` to the end of the defined command line, just inside the single quotes, but keeping it as `%O %S` (upper case).  That works for me.  If it works for you, I'll convert this to an answer (with explanation).

Comment: @JohnCollins both issues have been solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difficulty is that both `emacs/auctex` and `latexmk` need to be configured, and there has been a confusion about what belongs where. `Auctex` invokes `latexmk`, and then `latexmk` has the job of invoking other programs, like `pdflatex` as needed.

The code in `.emacs` is for configuring `emacs/auctex` so that it will be able to call `latexmk`.  It needs to contain

```
;; ============ Latexmk setup ==============                                        
(defun run-latexmk ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((TeX-save-query nil)
        (TeX-process-asynchronous nil)
        (master-file (TeX-master-file)))
    (TeX-save-document "")
    (TeX-run-TeX "latexmk"
                 (TeX-command-expand "latexmk -pdf %s" 'TeX-master-file)
                 master-file))
    (if (plist-get TeX-error-report-switches (intern master-file))
        (TeX-next-error t)
      (progn
        (demolish-tex-help)
        (minibuffer-message "latexmk: done."))))

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (lambda ()
    (push
     '("Latexmk" "latexmk -pdf %s" TeX-run-TeX nil t
       :help "Run Latexmk on file")
     TeX-command-list)))
```

Compared with the listing given in the question, there appears `%s` (with lower case) instead of `%O %S` and `%S`.  The `%s` denotes the name of the source file on the command line used to start `latexmk`.

The code in `.latexmkrc` is for configuring `latexmk`.  It needs to contain

```
$pdflatex = 'pdflatex --shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -synctex=1 %O %S';
```

This specifies to `latexmk` how to make the command line it uses to invoke `pdflatex`.  The `%O` and `%S` (with upper case) say where to put extra options and the source file.  Because of how `pdflatex` parses its command line, the `%O %S` needs to be at the end of the template for the command line.

This answer makes obsolete what appears in an answer to an earlier question on configuring `emacs` to use `latexmk`, at [How to make `latexmk` run the appropriate amount of times](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115247/how-to-make-latexmk-run-the-appropriate-amount-of-times)  However, the answers for a basic configuration of `emacs` given in another related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199678/how-to-call-latexmk-in-emacs-and-jump-to-next-error are correct.

Comment: Just one question.  Why does `%O %S` and `%S` cause the compiling of every figure in the folder when one is compiled and the compiling of non-called `.tex` files when the the master file was compiled?  I am just curious.

Comment: @dustin: When `%S` instead of `%s` appears in the specification of the `latexmk` command line in the file `.emacs`, it gets replaced by an empty string when the command line is built.  So `latexmk` is invoked with a command line with no filename.  As explained by @JimParis in his first comment to your question, `latexmk`'s default behavior in this situation is to compile all `.tex` files in the directory, just as you saw.