# AucTeX and Chapterbib

Tags: bibtex, emacs, auctex

Executing BibTeX via Auctex (RefTeX) in emacs (24.2.1) only creates a `.bbl` file for the master file in a multifile document. Yet, if one wants bibliographies for each chapter, BibTeX has to be run on each `.aux` file seperately. Is there a hidden option in Auctex (RefTeX) that activates this feature?

In the minimal example attached, only a `.bbl` file for `main.tex` is generated, but not for `incl.tex` and `incl2.tex`. Copying `main.bbl` to `incl.bbl` and `incl2.bbl` resolves the situation and both the citations and bibliographies can be found in the document.

TeX distro version: texlive 2012

RefTeX version: 4.31

**main.tex**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[round,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}

\begin{document}

\include{incl}
\include{incl2}

\end{document}


%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

**incl.tex**

```
\chapter{chap 1}

\input{inp}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{testbib} % BibTeX-File(s)


%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: "main"
%%% End:
```

**inp.tex**

```
\section{sect1}

some text and a ref: \cite{test_01}
%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: "main"
%%% End:
```

**incl2.tex**

```
\chapter{chap 2}
\section{sect1}

some text in chap2  and same ref: \cite{test_01}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{testbib} % BibTeX-File(s)

%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: "main"
%%% End:
```

**testbib.bib**

```
@book{test_01,
    title = {Test},
    publisher = {Test},
    author = {Adam Smith},
    year = {1982}
}
```

Comment: No, AUCTeX cannot cope with this situation, but you can run `latexmk` from AUCTeX, which instead is able to run `bibtex` on the relevant files.  On this site there are some suggestions about how to setup `latexmk` in AUCTeX, I'm using the configuration suggested [here](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/auctex/2012-10/msg00031.html).

Comment: Then I'm wondering why the [reftex manual is claiming support for chapterbib.](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/reftex/Chapterbib-and-Bibunits.html). Also is there a link missing in your comment giordano? Cheers

Comment: @StefanKuczera running the appropriate commands (`latex`, `bibtex`, etc...) is up to AUCTeX, not RefTeX, RefTeX just scans bibliography databases files to help you inserting bibliography entries `;-)`.  Which link are you referring to?  P.S. when you want to address someone in comments please start the message with `@USERNAME`, otherwise he/she won't be notified.

Comment: @giordano in your first comment you write "On this site there are...", but maybe you meant stackexchange. I guess it is not worth to submit this as an auctex problem again.

Comment: @StefanKuczera I didn't insert those links deliberately, I linked only the setup I actually use `:-)`.  If you want you can see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7811232/2442087) on stackoverflow, but that code is used also in [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/115247/31416) here on TeX.SE. You don't need to ask a new question, just change the tag of the question `;-)`.

Answer (score 1):

First, execute customize-group TeX-command. Expand TeX-command-list. Under the name field BibTeX, change the command field to bibtex %B

Next, go down to TeX-expand-list and insert a new key, %B. Add the following in the field for expander:
(lambda () (substring (TeX-current-file-name-master-relative) 0 -4))

["-4" above gets rid of the extension ".tex" from the file name that will be provided to BibTeX.]

Finally, save the customization.

The above steps will ensure that when you do BibTeX on a chapter in a subdirectory, the corresponding bbl file is created in that directory. I have tried this successfully on Windows and Mac Mavericks implementations.

Comment: Hi Simant, thanks for the answer and sorry for the late reply. Your command works in some cases. Yet it does not work if you execute C-c C-c from "inp.tex". Also the situation gets more complicated if you have multiple includes. I've updated the question, maybe someone wants to give it a go.

Comment: I can confirm that it works for Biber in Mac Mavericks.